# Adding a css Button to php/HTML

Tags: php

I was wondering if it is possible to use a button instead of a link in php?

Here is the code I have.

```
<?php echo "<a target ='_blank' href='$prefix/$filename' >View and Download Spec Sheet .PDF </a>";?>
```

I was looking to simply add a button instead of having text.

Thank you!

Comment: What is a CSS button?

Comment: No such thing as a CSS button, but if you want a button styled with CSS then it is possible.

Comment: You should give the `<a>` and `id` or `class`, so you can modify it with css into a button

Comment: Just add a class, then you're button will have a style :)

Comment: This should really not have anything to do with PHP. More of an HTML question.

Comment: `$effort="none";` --- definitely a no-brainer to do this. Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<?php echo "<form target ='_blank' action='$prefix/$filename'><button>View and Download Spec Sheet .PDF </button></form>";?>
```

Comment: Could you please explain *why* you down-voted my answer? It does exactly what the questioner asked.

Comment: Not me, but you have an href in your form. I'm assuming that should be `action`?

Comment: This one is similar to what I was looking for however it doesnt open the page I was looking for. Adding ACTION totally fixed the issue

Comment: @user3329725 Change `href` to `action` and this will work.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thank you. I didn't notice, but I've changed the answer now.

Comment: @user3329725 If this answer is useful, could you up-vote it, please? [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
<?php echo "<input type='button' value='your button text' onClick='window.location.href=(/"Your download location/",/"_blank/")'></input>"?>
</form>
```

Hope it helps!
You can add css to your button here.

Answer (score -1):

Just put a button inside the  tags like this. This question should really be an HTML question though not a PHP question.

```
<?php echo "<a target ='_blank' href='$prefix/$filename' >View and Download Spec Sheet .PDF </a>"; ?>
```